# Split stylesheet into multiple files with Webpack

Tags: css, sass, webpack, webpack-style-loader

We're using Webpack as our build system and have been experimenting with splitting our single, large stylesheet into multiple chunks.

Currently we do this by creating separate entry points but this gives us a problem; that we must duplicate many imports. This leads to a fragmented, spaghetti like dependency graph and loses any shared context that may be needed.

Ideally it would be great to stick with a single entry point, compiling a single large stylesheet but then split it.

For example given this single entry point main.scss:

```
// start:critical.css
@import "shared/normalize";
@import "shared/grid";
@import "shared/layout";
@import "shared/typography";
// end:critical.css

@import "shared/component/tabs";
@import "shared/component/modal";
@import "app/content-list";
@import "app/content";
@import "gallery";
```

It compiles 2 stylesheets; critical.css and main.css

Answer (score 1):

To solve this we ended up implementing a simple plugin that splits the output before writing it to files:

```
function () {
    const extractor = /\/\*!\s?start:([\w_-]+\.css)\s?\*\/[\S\s]+\/\*!\s?end:\1\s?\*\//g;
    const target = /start:([\w_-]+\.css)/;

    this.plugin('emit', (compilation, callback) => {
        const css = Object.keys(compilation.assets).filter(filename => /\.css$/.test(filename));

        css.forEach(filename => {
            const source = compilation.assets[filename].source();
            const blocks = source.match(extractor);

            blocks && blocks.forEach(block => {
                const name = block.match(target).pop();

                // add a new output file
                compilation.assets[`./public/${name}`] = {
                    source: () => block,
                    size: () => block.length
                };
            });

            // remove blocks from the parent
            compilation.assets[filename].source = () => source.replace(extractor, '');
        });

        callback();
    });
}
```